# Missing Template Arguments for pcl::gpu::EuclideanClusterExtraction in PCL-1.12

Tags: gpu, ubuntu-18.04, point-cloud-library, pcl

I am trying [this example](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/gpu/examples/segmentation/src/seg.cpp) to use PCL with GPU and get the error

> ~/gpu-pcl/main.cpp:85: error: missing template arguments before ‘gec’
> pcl::gpu::EuclideanClusterExtraction gec;

I have tried that example with pcl-1.11.1 and it worked well .But when updated to pcl-1.12.1, I get that error.
My work environment:
Ubuntu 18.04,
with Cmake version 3.20,
Is there anything that I have missed out??

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of pcl1.12:

> template
> class pcl::gpu::EuclideanClusterExtraction< PointT >

EuclideanClusterExtraction is a template class, thus the type of point of the point cloud is needed in the position of PointT, for example, PointXYZ.[https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1gpu_1_1_euclidean_cluster_extraction.html#details]

Comment: this partly correct, only that the error point to `pcl::gpu::EuclideanClusterExtraction` not `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction`

Comment: @Kaiwen Thanks for your answer. I have tried `pcl::gpu::EuclideanCluster<pcl::PointXYZ> gec;` And it crashed. Error: invalid device function ~/pcl/gpu/octree/src/cuda/octree_host.cu